# While debugging read all values from an odbcdatareader query

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, odbc, executereader

We want to read the values from "answer" while we are in debug mode in visual studio without taking them with getValues function, just for debug.

Is there any property shown in the local variable section where we can see the values?

```
Dim conex As Odbc.OdbcConnection
query = "SELECT one,two,three,four FROM table"

Dim com As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(query, conex)
answer = com.ExecuteReader

While answer.Read
 ...
End While
```

Some example images: 
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI08O.png)
[Debugging variables, local variables section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N4w6.png)

Comment: The reader loads the values from a row/each row as you call the read() method.  Only one row is "loaded" at anytime.  You could load a DataTable to look at them.

Comment: That is what I want, read the values from the row "loaded" by the Read() function.